# (Done) Reopen request:Resigned after working at company for 2 months. A year later, I would like to apply for a different position

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Resigned after working at company for 2 months. A year later, I would like to apply for a different position at that same company. Is it worth trying?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/149065/resigned-after-working-at-company-for-2-months-a-year-later-i-would-like-to-ap)

This was a highly voted question with many highly voted answers. Closing it as opinion based doesn't seem to reflect the feelings of the users in general.

I can understand that the current wording might not be the best, but I am hoping we can vote to reopen and/or edit as appropriate to bring it on topic. I feel like closing it because of potential wording seems like a technicality that doesn't reflect the value this question can add to our site. Leaving an employer and then trying to return is an interesting subject and it makes sense that people facing that decision would want answers.

I am going to attempt an edit but would welcome suggestions or additional edits.

Comment: Keep in mind what your goal in reopening it is. It was open for the better part of two days, received 6 positively received answers and the OP has accepted one of them. If you believe some facet of the question was not properly addressed, it might make more sense to ask a new question yourself. (To be clear, I don't mean to say that there's no point in improving this or other questions. This isn't [The First 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_48).)

Comment: I guess my point is, I don't think it's appropriate for a valuable question about an interesting subject to age out of on hold and get closed - even if the OP feels satisfied, I feel that part of our goal is to build a library of valuable questions and answers for others to use. Closing a question that could be a good contribution to that body of questions doesn't seem appropriate. I don't inherently think there's anything missing in terms of answers (although, maybe others do) and I don't have any additional question related to this myself.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Far too many questions are closed.

Comment: 4 votes to reopen now, one more needed

Answer (score 3):

I'm with you on this one - and have VTRO.

FWIW I also agree with your reasoning in the comments:

> I guess my point is, I don't think it's appropriate for a valuable question about an interesting subject to age out of on hold and get closed - even if the OP feels satisfied, I feel that part of our goal is to build a library of valuable questions and answers for others to use. Closing a question that could be a good contribution to that body of questions doesn't seem appropriate. I don't inherently think there's anything missing in terms of answers (although, maybe others do) and I don't have any additional question related to this myself.

That the OP in this instance appeared to have reached a resolution is irrelevant, if the question is worthy of being open it should remain so. For the benefit of future visitors and for the avoidance of setting inappropriate precedents regarding closures. Leaving useful and valuable questions to their closed state only makes it harder to keep other valuable questions in the future from being closed.